# How to add a tooltip in a entire row in vuetify data-table

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm trying to add a v-tooltip in a entire row in vuetify data table, i just want to add in a specific row of the array, when the item.confirmed is false then the line that has it will have a tooltip , i managed to do it but just with one value and not with a entire row. The tooltip message is in the array and the vuetify tooltip structure makes more difficult to do it, anyone could help me?

Code:

```
<app-table
        :loading="loading.tableDetails"
        :headers="headersDetailTable"
        :items="uploadTable.lines"
        :items-per-page="5"
      >
        <template #body="{ items }">
          <tbody>
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <template #activator="{ on }">
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" v-on="on">
                  <td>
                    {{ item.sku }}
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ item.productName }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.totalValue }}</td>
                  <td v-if="!item.confirmed">{{ item.invalidLine }}</td>
                </tr>
              </template>
              <span>{{ item.detail }}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </tbody>
        </template></app-table
      >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do it using mouseover and mouseleave

```
<app-table
      :loading="loading.tableDetails"
      :headers="headersDetailTable"
      :items="uploadTable.lines"
      @mouseleave.native="hideTooltipMessage"
    >
      <template #body="{ items }">
        <v-tooltip v-model="showTooltip" allow-overflow bottom>
          <template #activator="{}">
            <tbody>
              <tr
                v-for="(item, index) in items"
                :key="index"
                @mouseover="
                  showTooltipMessage({
                    message: item.detail,
                  })
                "
              >
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ item.sku }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ item.productName }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ item.quantity }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ item.value }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ item.totalValue }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <v-layout justify-center>
                    {{ !item.confirmed ? item.invalidLine : undefined }}
                  </v-layout>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </template>
          <template v-if="showTooltipInvalidMessage && showTooltip">
            <span>{{ showTooltipInvalidMessage }}</span>
          </template>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
    </app-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#props and saw that your code is missing the `attrs` shown in the example:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Bottom
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>Bottom tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
```

You could try modifying your code like the following. You can also conditionally render the row wrapped in a tooltip if `item.confirmed` is false.

```
<app-table
        :loading="loading.tableDetails"
        :headers="headersDetailTable"
        :items="uploadTable.lines"
        :items-per-page="5"
      >
        <template #body="{ items }">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-if="item.confirmed">
               *Row without a tooltip goes here*
            </tr>
            <v-tooltip v-else bottom>
              <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <tr
                  v-for="(item, index) in items"
                  :key="index"
                  v-on="on"
                  v-bind="attrs"
                >
                  <td>
                    {{ item.sku }}
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ item.productName }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.totalValue }}</td>
                  <td v-if="!item.confirmed">{{ item.invalidLine }}</td>
                </tr>
              </template>
              <span>{{ item.detail }}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </tbody>
        </template></app-table
      >
```

Comment: It doesn't works well, i need to show the full data table with the valids and invalid lines, i'm working on this the whole day haha , i need to check the array and show the tooltip in the invalid line, and the message in this code (item.detail) is the tooltip message, and it is inside the array so i can't put the item.detail out of the v-for like in my code because i need to check all the lines, but i'm stuck in how i can do it haha

Comment: I checked the docs again. It says you can control the visibility of the tooltip using v-model as well: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#visibility You could try setting a `show` variable in the v-model to only be true if the line is invalid.

Comment: i was able to fix it, i had to use mouseover and mouseleave, it's working for now, thanks a lot